# xUnit console runner cannot find json files with MS Test runner

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, xunit

I've got a class that I want to test with xUnit. This class loads a .json file containing configuration for this class in the constructor. By default, this json file is loaded from the current directory. This works fine in my application, as it can resolve the current working directory. This json file has the `Build Action = Content` and `Copy to output directory = Copy Always` to ensure the file is always along side the DLL files.

However, when calling the tests from within the VisualStudio test runner, the DLL's are run from the tempory files location: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\3c081508-0a25-45f0-8813-48d4fcabccaa\3c081508-0a25-45f0-8813-48d4fcabccaa\assembly\dl3\4175808c\f164e239_d1a1d201\SomeLibrary.dll` where each DDL required is in a separate file, and the .json file is nowhere to be seen. This means the code that loads the .json file from the current ddl location is failing. The functionality happens when running the tests from both within VisualStudio, or from within the xUnit.console application.

To overcome this, I've added a configuration option, and if that configuration option exists (which I add to my test project only), then use that path instead of trying to load the path from the current ddl. However this is now failing in bamboo, as that path is invalid when executed on the build server.

Is there anyway to get the temporary path programatically to where the .json file is... Or someway to disable using these temporary files and just use the actual bin dir in the project build dir for the VisualStudio test runner?

Currently using VisualStudio 2017 and xUnit 2.2.0.

Cheers, 
Justin

Answer (score 0):

There is this option for xunit tests called **Shadow-copy assemblies being tested**. It ensures that the assemblies being tested are copied elsewhere to allow the original assemblies to be modified while running and without affecting the tests.
Turning off this feature should help in your case.

Shadow-copy assemblies being tested  can be turned off in Visual Studio at 
**Resharper** -> **Options** -> **Tools** -> **Unit Testing** -> **Shadow-copy assemblies being tested**.